# egrep multiple string regex on line begin

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am trying to print lines of a file that begin with either 'foo' or 'bar' piped in from output of another command called 'list' for this example. 
It looks like
list | egrep 'foo|bar' > file.txt
It works except it picks up 'foo' or 'bar' anywhere in the line, not just at the beginning. I have tried all sorts of variations trying to use regex '^' before and after the quotes, replacing egrep with grep -P, and moving the quotes around in different ways. I can't figure out how to force it to use those terms only when they occur at the start of a line.

Comment: `grep -E '^(foo|bar)' file`

Comment: didn't work, getting a 0 line file

Comment: I figured it out, the device I'm working with, although it is some kind of flavor of Linux that has grep and egrep, doesn't work. If I take the file to another box running RHEL, this does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `^` in front of both `foo` and `bar`:

```
echo -e "fooOK\nbarOK\n--fooNOK\n--barNOK" | egrep "^foo|^bar"
fooOK
barOK
```

or use parens like @anubhava suggests.

Comment: Also didn't work, getting a 0 line file. I had already tried this particular way.